# Corrupt openssl encrypted file when decrypted in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography

I have a mysql dump file which is Gzipped and then encrypted in OpenSSL.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in input.gz -out output.gz.enc -pass pass:"some_pass_phrase"
```

when I try to decrypt it using NodeJS I get a corrupt file that I cannot unzip.

```
function decryptBackupFile() {
    var enc_key = GetEnvironmentVariable("ENC_KEY");
    var input = fs.createReadStream('/Users/afiku/Documents/input.sql.gz.enc');
    var output = fs.createWriteStream('/Users/afiku/Documents/output.sql.gz');

    var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', enc_key);
    decrypt.setAutoPadding(false);

    input.pipe(decrypt).pipe(output);
    output.on('finish', function(){
        console.log('Finished unarchiving');   
    });
}
```

I didn't get any error or exception and the resulting file is a bit smaller than the encrypted file.

the passphrase is correct. I tried decrypting it using openssl in bash and it worked...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bytes 8 to 15 of the OpenSSL output are the salt. Node.js doesn't use a salt, so you will have to implement EVP_BytesToKey with the salt parameter yourself. Are you sure you want to do that? Why don't you use an actual 256 bit key instead of a password? It would be much easier.

Comment: I don't have access to the input source, Cannot change the encryption method for the file

Comment: You could just invoke the openssl command from node. There is no need to implement it.